# WebGL (1) rendering to a texture results in: "GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Draw framebuffer is incomplete"

Tags: shader, webgl, framebuffer

Using this helper function we initilize framebuffer and texture:

```
protected _createTextureAndFramebuffer(gl, width, height, data) {
    const tex = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.ALPHA, width, height, 0, gl.ALPHA, gl.FLOAT, data);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(
        gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
    return {tex: tex, fb: fb};
}
```

Then we are rendering on the texture using the framebuffer:

```
const texFbPair1 = this._createTextureAndFramebuffer(gl, width, height, data);

gl.useProgram(this._blurProgram);

gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, texFbPair1.fb);
```

And finally using this generated texture on another shader program as a texture input:

```
gl.useProgram(this._isoBandProgram);
        gl.getExtension('OES_standard_derivatives');
        gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float')

        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE2);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texFbPair1.tex);
        gl.uniform1i(this._tileBlurTextureLocation, 2);
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

Unfortunately this results in the following console output (and a blank screen):
**[.WebGL-0x3fd40039bf00] GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Draw framebuffer is incomplete**

Is anyone familiar with that error message? Unfortunately it is hard to find many other instances online with that error.

Comment: `gl.ALPHA` is not a color renderable format.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Unfortunatelly, even when replacing

```gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null)```
with
```gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.ALPHA, width, height, 0, gl.ALPHA, gl.FLOAT, data);```
The error remains

Comment: maybe you don't pass a valid `width` and `height` to your function?

Comment: @LJᛃ I just looked, and all of the width and heights are 256.